# how to solve the issue of missing datafile and tablespace

Tags: oracle

how to solve the issue datafile mistakenly deleted something

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf'
```

```
SQL> startup;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  835104768 bytes
Fixed Size                  2293880 bytes
Variable Size             591400840 bytes
Database Buffers          239075328 bytes
Redo Buffers                2334720 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open


SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
alter database open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf'
```

Comment: what led you to this problem in the first place, and what did you do to restore the missing file? do you have an RMAN backup of the datafiles and archivelogs to work with?

Comment: try to recover it via sqlplus

Comment: sqlplus / as sysdba and then type recover database; and afterwards alter database open resetlogs;

Comment: @Bob that will only work if the OP has an RMAN backup to work with, which has not been established. The error message implies some sort of media recovery may already have taken place, but there hasn't been any detail provided as to what sort. Need to know those things to accurately provide instruction or advice on what to do next.

Comment: @pmdba That is true, but since he want's to open the database with resetlogs, it cannot hurt to try and recover the database. The sequence# will start from scratch.